# NSInternalInconsistencyException - "request for layout attributes for decoration view of kind MSCollectionElementKindCurrentTimeHorizontalGridline

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

The application I work on is displaying a CollectionView in form of a calendar. 
To simplify that we used the [MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout](https://github.com/monospacecollective/MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout) from github. 
Now it comes with multiple additional decoration views like a red line, which represents the current time in the calendar.

In our implementation there is also the possibility of filtering for different types, so the calendar not always displays the same kind/amount of cells. Unfortunately sometimes the application crashes just out of nowhere, when it should display the red timeline:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for layout attributes for decoration view of kind MSCollectionElementKindCurrentTimeHorizontalGridline in section 0 when there are only 0 sections in the collection view'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x034761e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02fcb8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03476048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x00e2f4de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x018eb290 -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:atIndexPath:] + 228
    5   UIKit                               0x018b5764 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 242
    6   UIKit                               0x018a8036 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 381
    7   UIKit                               0x018a9775 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4730
    8   UIKit                               0x018ad65f -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 265
    9   UIKit                               0x012d0964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02fdd82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    11  QuartzCore                          0x026a445a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    12  QuartzCore                          0x02698244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    13  QuartzCore                          0x026980b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    14  QuartzCore                          0x025fe7fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    15  QuartzCore                          0x025ffb85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    16  QuartzCore                          0x02600258 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0343e36e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0343e2bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0341c254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0341b9d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0341b7eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x049615ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x0496142b GSEventRun + 104
    24  UIKit                               0x01261f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    25  CariAudit                           0x001036ad main + 141
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x039d9701 start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x00000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Now I know that with this custom layout, many people get this error message when they change the underlying data of the collectionView and the solution to this is to call "**invalidateLayoutCache**" on the layout. The only problem is that I already have that in my code and it gets called before calling **reloadData** on the collectionView.

Does anyone maybe have an idea/approach for solving this kind of problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of searching I finally managed to find the error.
The problem was that the MSCollectionViewCalendarLayout missed to empty the Attributes-Dictionaries
***currentTimeIndicatorAttributes*** and ***currentTimeHorizontalGridlineAttributes***.

To fix the error all I had to do was to expand the **invalidateLayoutCache** method with the following:

```
[self.currentTimeIndicatorAttributes removeAllObjects];
[self.currentTimeHorizontalGridlineAttributes removeAllObjects];
```